# How to get simple array from php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have resultArray from request at database via php:

```
$req = "SELECT gauss, moc FROM v_gauss";

$query = pg_query($dbconn, $req);
    if (!$query) {
      echo "T - An error occurred.\n";
     exit;
    }

$resultArray = array(); 

while($row = pg_fetch_array($query, null, PGSQL_ASSOC))
{
  $resultArray[] = $row;    
}

echo ($callback ? $callback . '(' : '') . json_encode($resultArray,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) . ($callback ? ')' : '');
```

get:

```
[{"gauss":0.0039791959647625,"moc":135},
...
{"gauss":0.0039972978485087,"moc":35}]
```

how to achieve simple array like this:

```
[0.0039791959647625,135],
...
[0.0039972978485087,35]
```

I am trying various combination with pg_fetch_array, pg_fetch_row, array_merge and still without luck.

It must be number array because I need this setof to render chart.

Comment: How about `PGSQL_NUM ` instead of `PGSQL_ASSOC`?

Comment: You need to fetch with numeric keys and keep it as an array, not converting to JSON.

Comment: Yeah, it's it! Thanks a lot, You have saved me time ;) Eddie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `PGSQL_NUM` instead of `PGSQL_ASSOC`

> Using PGSQL_NUM, pg_fetch_array() will return an array with numerical
>   indices

Like:

```
while($row = pg_fetch_array($query, null, PGSQL_NUM))
{
  $resultArray[] = $row;    
}
```

Doc: [PGSQL_NUM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-array.php)

---

Another option is using `array_values()` to get all the values from the array and indexes the array numerically.